# ExpandableListView indicator is not aligned correctly

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I created a ExpandableListView programmatically and I'm using TextView for the groupitems. I now get a problem with the groupIndicator which propably doesn't occur when the ExpandableListView is declared within a xml : The indicator is drawn directly to top of the groupItem ("no paddingTop"). I'm using padding on my TextViews so it looks like the indicator is not aligned to the TextView in height. How can I align the indicator correctly?

Thx

EDIT:
within my custom BaseExpandableListAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Context c = context.get();
    if(c==null)
        return null;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = new TextView(c);
        TextView t = (TextView) convertView;
        t.setText(groupData.get(groupPosition));
        t.setPadding(left, groupPadding, left, groupPadding);  // left '=' android.R.attr.expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft
        t.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, groupTextSize);
        t.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        return t;
    }
    TextView t = (TextView) convertView;
    t.setText(groupData.get(groupPosition));
    return t;

}
```

This is a screenshot of one unexpanded groupItem :
[image]

As you can see the indicator drawable touches the top-edge of the groupItem.

EDIT2:
I set a custom Drawable as indicator in the hope that it will fix my problem. At first my drawable was stretched to fit groupItem's height. I'm now using 9patchs which prevent the indicator from getting stretched, but this cause the indicator to be aligned to the bottom (instead of to the top as before). Well, still the same problem just reversed. Any ideas how I can fix the problem using my custom drawable? Maybe there is a way to add padding to the indicator (because I know the drawable height and the groupItem's height)?

```
//indicator_selector.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_right" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down" />

</selector>

//in MainActivity.onCreate()
expView = new ExpandableListView(context);
indicator = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.indicator_selector);
expView.setGroupIndicator(indicator);
expView.setIndicatorBounds(expView.getPaddingLeft(), expView.getPaddingLeft()+indicator.getIntrinsicWidth());
```

Comment: Show some code. Screenshot would be a nice bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this question and the answer of coderat I figured out how to solve my problem using 9patches [ [ExpandableListView - group indication is stretch to fit the text size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212805/expandablelistview-group-indication-is-stretch-to-fit-the-text-size/19322715#19322715) ] :

[image]