# Custom icons in expandablelistview have distorted dimensions

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

I have an expandablelistview that needs to have custom arrows. I tried setting the groupIndicator to a selector like so:

```
<ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/home_drawer_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:childDivider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:groupIndicator="@drawable/expandable_list_view_selector" />

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down" android:state_expanded="true" />
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_right" />
</selector>
```

However, for some reason this is distorting the dimensions of the arrows, see below:

[image]

Any idea why they're being distorted, and how to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExpandableListView - group indication is stretch to fit the text size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212805/expandablelistview-group-indication-is-stretch-to-fit-the-text-size)

Comment: It appears that post was related to the group header's height stretching the image, whereas mine was due to padding. However bwacher's answer is what I ended up doing, although my answer has more details so maybe this is still useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was that I was setting padding on the TextView in the group header, which was then distorting the image. I found the whole default group header and custom indicator to be extremely cumbersome to work with, you can't really customize the row at all without distorting the image, so I ended up using a custom view for the group header instead.

Set the ExpandableListView's groupIndicator to @null:

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:groupIndicator="@null" />
```

Add a custom group header, in my case ListViewGroupHeader.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/group_header_arrow"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/group_header_title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/group_header_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Set the custom layout in your adapter's GetGroupView method, keying off of the isExpanded property for which image to show:

```
var layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)ApplicationContext.Activity.GetSystemService (Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            var view = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ListViewGroupHeader, null);
            var arrowImageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.group_header_arrow);
            var titleTextView = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.group_header_title);

            arrowImageView.SetImageResource (isExpanded ? Resource.Drawable.arrow_down : Resource.Drawable.arrow_right);
            titleTextView.Text = title;
            if (isExpanded && colorExpandedBlue) {
                arrowImageView.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.arrow_down_blue);
                titleTextView.SetTextColor (ApplicationContext.Activity.Resources.GetColor (Resource.Color.standard_blue));
            }
            return view;
```

Answer (score 3):

I did a simpler solution, not very elegant, but works. Used a layer list, positioning the drawable resource with padding on top and bottom, this results in a drawable with the expected proportion of my expandable list view. The amount of padding may be different to your view...
The icon I used was downloaded at https://material.io/icons/

Create two layer list drawable:

File ic_expand_more_expandable_list.xml in drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_expand_less_white_24dp"
        android:top="8dp"
        android:bottom="8dp"
 />
</layer-list>
```

File ic_expand_more_expandable_list.xml in drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_expand_more_white_24dp"
        android:top="8dp"
        android:bottom="8dp"
 />
</layer-list>
```

and use then as your state:

File group_arrow.xml in drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_expand_less_expandable_list"
        android:state_expanded="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_expand_more_expandable_list" />
</selector>
```

And then add it as the group indicator of the ExpandableListView

```
android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_arrow"
```

It is working perfectly here in all tested resolutions.