# Custom group expanding icon in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

[image]

I am trying to use a custom icon for group expand and collapse state of an ExpandableListView. But this doesn't seem to work. The icons doesn't get changed even when the Output messages are working sequentially.

```
    explistView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id)
        {
            groupIndicator = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.group_indicator);
            if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition))
            {
                System.out.println("1");
                parent.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                System.out.println("2");
                groupIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.expand_icon_35x35);
                System.out.println("3");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } 
            else
            {
                System.out.println("4");
                parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
                System.out.println("5");
                groupIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.collapse_icon_35x35);
                System.out.println("6");
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you set setGroupIndicator(null)?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293738/androidchange-indicator-icon-and-size-of-expandablelistview-used-for-navigation)

You can change the icons by using following:-

```
<ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/list"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:groupIndicator="@drawable/settings_selector"
   />
```

and Setting selector is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/up_arrow" android:state_empty="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/down_arrow" android:state_expanded="true"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: I have used this already and it works fine but the icon gets stretched. So I switched to the above method.

Comment: @VeronikaGilbert try resizing your icons to 32*32 dp

Comment: @VeronikaGilbert can you please upload a pic.It may be an issue with icon slicing.it should not be code specific.

Comment: I have added the image where the icon expands itself to fill in the space.

Comment: Can you suggest me the size of the image which I need to use?

Comment: @VeronikaGilbert i see the issue is that in expandable list view group indicator expands to fit the size of view.So you can use 9 patch images.I googled it an find the following accepted answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212805/expandablelistview-group-indication-is-stretch-to-fit-the-text-size and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212805/expandablelistview-group-indication-is-stretch-to-fit-the-text-size.Please check these answers as they may help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,**android:state_empty="true"** is not working.
So, I changed it to **android:state_expanded="false"** .

```
<ExpandableListView 
       android:id="@+id/expl"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:groupIndicator="@drawable/settings_selector"/>
```

And

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/plus_arrow" android:state_expanded="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/minus_arrow" android:state_expanded="false"/>
</selector>
```

I hope it helps.